# Locking Document Visibility settings in DocuSign for Specific Senders

Tags: docusignapi

I've successfully created DocuSign envelopes with a single button click from Salesforce through REST API by auto-populating documents, recipients and Document Visibility settings through this API call.

In order to achieve this, Document Visibility settings has been set to "Must sign to view unless Sender". Hence this section can be edited by any sender. The **Document Visibility** section in the Draft envelope **should be locked/hidden for specific senders**.

Is there any feature available to achieve this in New DocuSign Experience? Can this done through Apex REST API?

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Only a sender of a specific envelope will be able to edit the "Document Visibility" setting of that envelopes not the other senders of that DS Account. So do you want the sender who has created an envelope can also not edit the Document Visibility settings on an envelope?

Comment: Yes Amit. Sender of the envelope should not edit the visibility settings. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot disable Document Visibility for the sender of an envelope. Since you are using API integration, you can send an envelope using API credentials and add the requestor of an envelope (logically a sender) as first recipient in the routing order as CC recipient. This way requestor can monitor the envelope but will not do any activity on an envelope including Document Visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will try this way.